# Winston 3.9.0 not working on node 12 because of triple-beam engine restriction

Tags: node.js, npm, winston

I want to use the latest version of `winston@3.9.0` using `node.js@12.22.12` but I can't because one of winston's dependencies, `triple-beam@1.4.1` has an engine restriction >= 14.0.0.

Any ideas how I can bypass this? Maybe forcing the version of `triple-beam@1.3.0` which doesn't have the engine restriction? Also in winston's package.json triple-beam is declared as ~1.3.0 so it could be 1.3.0...

Comment: The correct answer here is "stop using Node 12"; it's been end-of-life for 1 year and 3 months (30 Apr 2022).

Comment: That's not a solution unfortunately, otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Neither is running out-of-support, insecure software. Either way, unless you're running npm with [`engine-strict`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#engine-strict), it's just a warning, and of course you can install `triple-beam@1.3.0` explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't work if I explicitly specify in my package.json triple-beam@1.3.0 it still uses 1.4.1

Comment: and apparently it is a engine-strict environment.

Comment: I ended up using [resolutions](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md)
  "resolutions": {
    "triple-beam": "1.3.0"
  },

Comment: `resolutions` is a yarn only thing afaik, and you only mentioned npm and never mentioned you're using yarn.